# dispacthing actions creator gets called twice using componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I call action creator using **componentWillMount method,** then it gets called twice. look at below screenshot of the result.

[image]

this is my action **creator** :

```
export function fetchAdmin(){
    return (dispatch)=>{
        axios.get(`${Config.API_URL}/admin`,{
            headers: { authorization: localStorage.getItem('token')}
        })
            .then(response => {
                   return dispatch({
                        type: FETCH_DATA,
                        payload: response.data
                    });
                }
            )
            .catch(response => {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }
}
```

and this is my **reducer** :

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from '../actions/types';

export function admin(state= {}, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_DATA:
            return {...state, lists: action.payload };
        default:
            return { state, lists: 'YEY!'}
    }


}
```

and this is my container and the way i call my action creator using componentWillMount.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from 'actions/admin_action';


class Admin extends Component{
    componentWillMount(){
        this.props.fetchAdmin()
    }
    renderData(){
        var lists = this.props.lists;
        console.log(lists);
    }
  render(){

        return(
          <div>
            {this.renderData()}
          </div>
        )
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     return { lists: state.admin.lists };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Admin);
```

from the screenshot i assume that render() gets called twice. the first call goes to default action creator so that the result is "YEY!" and the second is the valid one.

can someone explain it to me why componentWillMount perform like this and actually in the first render i just wanna my array not "YEY!" how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: It is not recommended to trigger data load in `componentWillMount`. You should do that in `componentDidMount`

Comment: owh really? whyy?? @just-boris

Comment: This Twitter thread contains some explanation https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/790581793397305345

Comment: Also official documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount
`componentWillMount`: Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions in this method.
`componentDidMount`: If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem here! When your component render first time, it reached the rendering before the logic `componentWillMount` is finished, so:

**First time rendering**: Your component is rendered while the `lists` in global state is the default which equals `YEY!`.

**Second time rendering**: When data is fetched successfully, after that the reducer change in the `lists` in the global state with the fetched ones, after that your component detects the change due to `mapStateToProps` that got the `lists` from the global state.

Needless to say that React component is re-rendered on propsChange, that's why there is a method `componentWillReceiveProps` so that you can add some logic (if you need) on each time your props change.

This behavior allows you to handle waiting the data to be fetched by:

- Add a loading spinner.
- Get your layout rendered.
- Get the other components in your page rendered.

Comment: where should i put componentWillReceiveProps ? i changed componentWillMount to componentWillReceiveProps the result is only "YEY" @Basim

Comment: This is just useful if your use-case need some logic, but in this case I don't think so.

Comment: Actually in the first render i just wanna my array not "YEY!" how to solve this problem? @Basim

Comment: In your default case in reducer just return the state as is `return state` but you need to initialize the `lists` array, so it woud be `return { state, lists: []}`

Comment: i changed it and the result is empty array [] on default reducer. is it possible to call `FETCH_DATA` only, i dont want my container calls default reducer. is it possible? @Basim

Comment: and what do you think will happen till the data is fetched, UI-wise?

Comment: honestly im new in react world and it changes the way i think about fetching data. probably i can give spinner while data is fetching.. i dunno whether my comment answer your question or not @Basim

Comment: Yeh and that exactly shows you how Redux architecture is amazing, you can read more about it and get deeper. I hope I can make it clear for you. Good luck in your project.

Comment: to sum up my question, If the data is not ready i can call action creator and dispatch reducer to change spinner flag to be true, after it's ready, i map the data. is it correct? @Basim

Comment: Just one action is needed to be dispatched, but two different states you'll have, one with the list still empty (so you can put the loading spinner) another when the state is full with list data.

Comment: thank you so much, i will learn react redux deeper after this at least my curiosity has been answered. appreciate your time @Basim

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous. The HTTP request you are performing is asynchronous. This means that Javascript execution continues while the HTTP request is still pending.

So React already renders while the state is still 'Yey'. This is how it should be and also the beauty of Redux, actions are fire and forget, they are not blocking. If React would wait for the HTTP request to finish, user experience would be horrible!

If you don't want it to render 'Yey'. You should show a loader or something while the request is still pending.

Comment: thank you sir for the explaination, it makes me clear at the moment. ^^